# Using a custom drawn tilemap inside swiftui in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have created a very simple tilemap, using a tileSet in Xcode. I did this in a swiftUI project, so the tileMap exists inside a .sks file. I am curious about how to get this existing tileMap inside of my swiftui view? I wasn't able to find a working solution on the net, and i don't fully understand how these SKTilemapnode and all those other SK... things work. I hope somebody is able to explain this to me and how to implement this into a swiftui project! I will add some pictures to show how my project looks like currently! Don't mind the silly design of the tilemap though, that doesn't matter for now, I just would like to get this tilemap working as a gamescene inside of swiftui.

[image: The tilemap]
[image: The swiftui code]

Hope somebody can help me,

Rene